# Cannot predict value with linear regression. 'float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime''

Tags: python, stock

I am trying to use linear regression to predict a known closing price using python. I am receiving the following error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/username/Documents/Python/StockDataCairn.py', wdir='C:/Users/username/Documents/Python')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-8b690adea22c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/username/Documents/Python/StockDataCairn.py', wdir='C:/Users/username/Documents/Python')

  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/username/Documents/Python/StockDataCairn.py", line 33, in <module>
    regressor.predict(pred_date)

  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 221, in predict
    return self._decision_function(X)

  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 204, in _decision_function
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])

  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 496, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)

  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

Here is my following code:

```
#import modules needed
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import style
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#styel of plot
style.use('ggplot')

#set date limits
pred_date= dt.datetime(2019,11,1)
end = dt.date(2018,1,1)
start = dt.date(2016,1,1)

#gather data from yahoo
df = web.DataReader("BP.L", 'yahoo', start, end)

df = df.reset_index()
prices = df['Adj Close'].tolist()
dates = df.index

dates = np.reshape(dates, (len(dates), 1))
prices = np.reshape(prices, (len(prices), 1))
#print(len(dates))
#Define Linear Regressor Object
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(dates, prices)
pred_date = np.reshape(pred_date,(1,-1))
regressor.predict(pred_date)
print(regressor.predict(pred_date))
#Visualize Results
plt.plot(dates, prices, color='blue', label= 'Actual Adjusted Closing Price') #plotting the initial datapoints
plt.plot(dates, regressor.predict(dates), color='red', linewidth=2, label = 'Predicted Price') #plotting the line made by linear regression
plt.title('Linear Regression | Time vs. Price')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Adjusted Closing Price')
plt.show()
```

The issue appear to be with the `pred_date` part of the code. I cannot figure out how to fix this however. If I make the pred_date = to a number then the code appears to work. I am unsure on how to address this issue.

Comment: Try using `.toordinal()` on the dates, e.g. `dt.datetime(2019,11,1).toordinal()`

Comment: This allows me to see the graph, however, it produces a prediction value of 250180.18 which is far too high

Comment: Try differencing the dates.

Answer (score 0):

What you think of as `dates` using `df.index` is actually a range index, so a numeric type. This is why you can train your model on this data.

However, the `pred_date` is an actual date, and you cannot fit a linear model on datetime objects. You need to encode this as other variables, see for instance [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311494/best-practice-for-encoding-datetime-in-machine-learning#311498).